# Generalized transpose/ permute dimensions

Tags: algorithm, clojure, lisp

I need something like MatLab's [`permute(A, order)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) or Mathematica's [`Transpose[list, {n,...}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) for Clojure vectors (of vectors of...).

Swapping the first and second dimension is easy: `(apply mapv vector x)` but I'd like an inteface like the functions mentioned above where I can give a new order of dimensions, i.e. `(permute x [1 0])` would be that transposition, `(permute x [0 1 2])` identity for 3 dimensions etc.

Example for a Mathematica list of lists of lists:

```
Array[a, {1, 2, 3}]
{{{a[1, 1, 1], a[1, 1, 2], a[1, 1, 3]},
  {a[1, 2, 1], a[1, 2, 2], a[1, 2, 3]}}}

Transpose[%, {3, 2, 1}]
{{{a[1, 1, 1]}, {a[1, 2, 1]}},
 {{a[1, 1, 2]}, {a[1, 2, 2]}},
 {{a[1, 1, 3]}, {a[1, 2, 3]}}}
```

An existing library would be best of course, but any pointers would be appreciated.
Numeric libraries usually just wrap a one-dimensional array and adjust the offsets, but I want actual lists.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix

Comment: as usual that library works with its own matrix type only (probably just returning views with adjusted offsets) and: `(defn transpose "If ordering is provided, will re-order dimensions according to the provided order." ([m] (mp/transpose m)) ([m ordering] (TODO)))` it's not implemented yet.

Comment: One could implement this for all matrix types with Fare's [LIL](http://www.cliki.net/lisp-interface-library)